# Empty on collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created database and have make one collection with the name **staff** there,  I have put 3 data and it is showing on mongodb compass. But will try to fetch staff I got empty array. I am baby with this mongo db envirnment so I am unknow where did I get mess on my code.

Here, I have two files. one server.js which is main file and another is model file

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Staff = require("./staff");
const dbname = "mydbname";
const dbpass = "mypassword";
const dbuser = "meuser";
    mongoose.connect(
"mongodb+srv://"+dbuser+":"+dbpass+"@cluster0.ovjvl.mongodb.net/"+dbname+"?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => console.warn("db connection done"))
.catch((error) => console.warn("DB Not Connect", error));
Staff.find({},(err,data)=>{
if(err) console.warn(err)
  console.warn("Data :",data)
})
```

**staff.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let staffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name:String,
designation:String,
gender:String,
salary:mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128,
skills:mongoose.Schema.Types.Array})
module.exports = mongoose.model('staff',staffSchema)
```

While I run my app I got below ouput

```
db connection done
Data : []
```

But am expecting some data on array.

**Note :** For security reason, I have mention dbname,user & password is fake.

Comment: Do you have data on the staff model also why are you naming your file server if your model is staff?

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. Please double-check if your collection name `staff` does not have any spelling error or any camel case letter miss-match if you have created it manually. (As you already saying that you have data in DB)

Comment: yes, my collection name is absolutly staff